# Design pattern for starting up dependent services

Tags: java, design-patterns, dependency-injection, guice

Suppose we have a Service that depends upon a definite set of other services to be available and started before this service can be initiailized and started. With a heavy usage of DI through google guice , we keep the service itself decoupled from the concrete services it depends upon. But then who is responsible for

1. Fetching the list of dependent services ?
2. Ensuring they are in correct state when they get injected into present service ?

Defining guice modules to list the dependent services seems a good way , and obviously one can write code in each particular case to ensure the sequence of startup - but is there any established/general design pattern for these type of problems ?

Comment: perhaps I need to add some context/info to make sense of my question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look into the [HK2 Run Level Service](https://hk2.java.net/2.3.0-b01/runlevel.html).  It may be possible to use the HK2 Run Level Service in combination with the [Guice Bridge](https://hk2.java.net/2.3.0-b01/guice-bridge.html) to achieve having run-level services in Guice.

RunLevel services allow you to have services that only come up after the system has reached a certain state, rather than having to list all the dependencies (which may only be functional dependencies, as opposed to java level dependencies) in your code explicitly.